# reading bits with for loop, I get 7 bits instead of 8, what's the wrong with this code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

**OutPuts:** 
TextBox 2 : FalseTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueFalseFalse

TextBox 3 : 1111100

My problem is why is that the first boolean of "TextBox 2" is "False" and the first integer of "TextBox 3" is 1 ? "TextBox 2" has 8 booleans while "TextBox 3" only has 7 bits. And apparently, in "TextBox 3, the first bit is not there. Where have I done wrong .. ? commentary has provided in the code. Please shed some light here.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim array() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\binfile.bin")

    Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(array)
        Using reader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(memory)

            ba1 = New BitArray(array)

            Dim bit_set As Integer

            For i As Integer = 0 To 7

                'to view all 8 bits in boolean format
                TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & ba1.Get(i)

                If ba1.Get(i) = False Then

                    boolean2bits = 0
                    'End If
                ElseIf ba1.Get(i) = True Then

                    boolean2bits = 1
                End If

                'to collect all 8 bits in integer format
                bit_set = bit_set & boolean2bits

                If (i = 7) Then
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next

           'to view collected bits in the text box
            TextBox3.Text = bit_set

        End Using
    End Using


End Sub
```

Comment: Your type choices are sloppy, *bit_set* must be a string.  Program for a while with Option Strict On at the top of your source code file to let the compiler help you get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because you are assigning the value `01111100` to the integer variable `bit_set`.  But of course, as an integer, that leading `0` is not significant, so it gets stripped out automatically, and gets simplified to simply `1111100`, because it is the same number after all.

If you don't want to lose the leading zero for display purposes, then you probably don't want `bit_set` to be of type `Integer`.  Just declare at as a `Dim bit_set As String`, and the leading zero will not disappear.

Comment: Hi there, I'm glad you were unblocked.  I noticed you accepted this answer, then unaccepted?  Was that intentional?  It's your choice :)

Comment: No, I don't know what happened, I might accidentally clicked it again .. :D .. Your Answer is very much accepted .. it's perfect .. :) Thanks again.

Comment: @Pretty_Girl: Ah no worries. Maybe you tried to accept more than one answer, which unfortunately cannot be done in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're making some progress towards your end goal Pretty_Girl.

Here are some snippets to take in and digest:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ba1 = New BitArray(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\binfile.bin"))

    Dim bits As New List(Of String)
    Dim bools As New List(Of String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To 7
        bools.Add(ba1.Get(i).ToString)
        bits.Add(If(ba1.Get(i), "1", "0"))
    Next

    'to view collected bits/bools in the text box
    TextBox2.Text = String.Join(",", bools.ToArray)
    TextBox3.Text = String.Join("", bits.ToArray)
End Sub
```

Alternate Version 2:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ba1 = New BitArray(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\binfile.bin"))

    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 7
        TextBox2.AppendText(ba1.Get(i).ToString & ",")
        TextBox3.AppendText(If(ba1.Get(i), "1", "0"))
    Next
End Sub
```

Alternate Version 3:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ba1 = New BitArray(File.ReadAllBytes("D:\binfile.bin"))

    Dim bits As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim bools As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For i As Integer = 0 To 7
        bools.Append(ba1.Get(i).ToString & ",")
        bits.Append(If(ba1.Get(i), "1", "0"))
    Next

    TextBox2.Text = bools.ToString
    TextBox3.Text = bits.ToString
End Sub
```